# Trying to Understand UWP Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, win-universal-app

So, I made a really simple attempt to try out data binding from a property of a class that I have, but, for whatever reason, the code actually do anything. It's not throwing any errors, but something must not be working right. I'm just currently testing if it'll behave like I want it to, which, in this case, will set the opacity of a rectangle to zero. Here's the xaml for the Data Template that doesn't seem to want to respond correctly:

```
        <HubSection x:Name="China" Width="440" Height="460" Background="#FF343434" Header="China" IsHeaderInteractive="True" Tapped="{x:Bind HubSectionTapped}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0,0,0">
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MainPageView">
                <Grid Height="460" Width="410" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="ChinaBackground">
                    <Image Source="Assets/chinaFlag.bmp" x:Name="ChinaFlag"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="ChinaSelected_Rect" Width="410" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="BlueViolet" Opacity="{x:Bind Opacity1}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
    public MainPageView TheMainPageView;

    public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += Timer_DyanmicResize;
        timer.Tick += Timer_SelectionIndicator;
        timer.Start();

        TheMainPageView = new MainPageView ();
    }
```

And finally, here's the class MainPageView that's referenced:

```
public class MainPageView
{
    public int Opacity1 {get; set;}
    public int Opacity2 {get;set;}
    public int Opacity3 { get; set; }

    public MainPageView()
    {
        this.Opacity1 = 0;
        this.Opacity2 = 0;
        this.Opacity3 = 0;
    }
}
```

In the XAML I included the xmlns:data="using:TestApp.Models" (models is the folder in which the class MainPageView is housed). As I said, it's not throwing errors, but it's not doing anything either, so I'm a bit at a loss of where to start addressing this because there aren't any errors to trace back. Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide

Answer (score 3):

**[HubSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hubsection)** uses a [**DataTemplate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx) to define the content for the section, content can be defined inline, or bound to a data source. When using binding in this `DataTemplate`, we need set `DataContext` property of `HubSection` to provide data source for the `DataTemplate`.

> **{x:Bind}** does not use the **DataContext** as a default source—instead, it uses the page or user control itself. So it will look in the code-behind of your page or user control for properties, fields, and methods.

This is right when you use `{x:Bind}` directly in page or user control. While Inside a `DataTemplate`, there is a little difference.

> Inside a **[DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx)** (whether used as an item template, a content template, or a header template), the value of **Path** is not interpreted in the context of the page, but in the context of the data object being templated. So that its bindings can be validated (and efficient code generated for them) at compile-time, a **DataTemplate** needs to declare the type of its data object using **x:DataType**.

For more information about Data binding in UWP, please check [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

To fix your issue, you just need to set `DataContext` in `HubSection` like following:

```
<HubSection x:Name="China" Width="440" Height="460" Background="#FF343434" Header="China" IsHeaderInteractive="True" Tapped="{x:Bind HubSectionTapped}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0,0,0" DataContext="{x:Bind TheMainPageView}">
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MainPageView">
        <Grid Height="460" Width="410" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="ChinaBackground">
            <Image Source="Assets/chinaFlag.bmp" x:Name="ChinaFlag"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="ChinaSelected_Rect" Width="410" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="BlueViolet" Opacity="{x:Bind Opacity1}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Here when using `{x:Bind}` in `HubSection`, it uses the page itself as its data source as `HubSection` is in the page directly. So it can get `TheMainPageView` field in the code-behind. But for the `{x:Bind}` in `DataTemplate`, it can't as
its data source is the data object being templated not the page. So we need to provide this data object by setting `DataContext` property of `HubSection`.

Answer (score 0):

Check you output window for errors but I imagine you might see a binding error in there.  Opacity is a double, you are using an int so will get a type conversion error.

Comment: So, after changing the properties to type double, nothing changed, but you were right in so far that my output was giving me a warning about it. Though, even after a clean rebuild, the problem still persists...

Comment: Where are you setting the data context to the instance of your MainPageView?

Comment: I didn't set it. According to this article, it defaults to the page that the control is on and searches for an instance instead, unless I'm reading it wrong. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension